# How to pass multiple parameter in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have created dynamic parameters, I passed two(ids and id) parameter in URL but do not know pass parameter in below htacces file could you solve this issue please

my htacces file:

`Options -MultiViews`

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/store\.html\?ids=([0-9]+)&id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]`

`RewriteRule ^ /store/%1? [R=301,L]`

`RewriteRule ^store/([0-9]+)$ /store.html?ids=$1&id=$2 [L]`

my URL is http://localhost/store.html?ids=kebab-bistro&id=196

Comment: To format blocks of code either use backtick fencing (ie. 3 backticks before and after the code block on separate lines) - or indent the entire block by 4 spaces (which is what the option on the formatting toolbar does for you).

Comment: "my URL is `http://localhost/store.html?ids=kebab-bistro&id=196`" - your URL _should be_ `/store/kebab-bistro/196` (although `/store/196/kebab-bistro`) is probably preferable.